# Concurrent xcodebuild for single iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, xcodebuild

I am building an Xcode project on Jenkins. I have two jobs, one for building a release ipa and one for infer static analysis on the same app. When I build those jobs serially, they are successful, but when both jobs are triggered simultaneously, one job (or sometimes both) fails. I think its because of dependency on any common Xcode workspace data.

for example, once job1 is running, starting job2 gave error,

> 13:41:08 ** CLEAN FAILED ** 13:41:08  13:41:08  13:41:08 The following
>   build commands failed: 13:41:08   Clean.Remove clean
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hgrzbfuhglcreddfnjywviabrjhl/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build

So, how can I successfully run both jobs simultaneously? On other words, which of the Xcode workspace data/folder needed to be separated to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Please describe the exact issue "it fails" and what exactly you mean "with "some common Xcode stuffs".

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Please see the edited question. by stuffs i meant anything on workspace dependent data/folder.

Comment: Check out the command line flags for setting the derived data directory.

Comment: only derived data directory is dependent? will it work?

Comment: I do not see why a Release build would conflict with "Debug-iphoneos" directory.